# Copy Data in table in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to transfer/copy data in to a table in a excel sheet. I have written the following code which works if there is no table and just normal structure.

```
Sub TransferData()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OverRides")
lastrow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Range("B5:B" & lastrow).CopyThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3)
Range("C5:C" & lastrow).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2)
Range("A5:A" & lastrow).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Now the data gets transferred but with a waterfall pattern like

```
                                                          1
                                                          2
                                                          3
                                                          4
                                   A
                                   B
                                   C
                                   D
      !
      @
      $
      %
```

Assuming this are 3 columns and 4 rows of data. Can anyone correct?

My desired result is that this data should be copied in line with other data.

```
Old Data              Old Data                Old Data
    !                     A                      1
    @                     B                      2
    $                     C                      3
    %                     D                      4
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  What is your desired result?

Comment: What is your input look like?

Comment: @chancea and @ katz I have updated my result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are "finding" the range to copy the data to, even after you copy the first set of data.  It is at the line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(...)
```

So instead just save that range and offset from it:

```
Sub TransferData()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OverRides")
lastrow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Dim startRange as Range 'save the range to this variable
set startRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp)

Range("B5:B" & lastrow).Copy startRange.Offset(1, 3)
Range("C5:C" & lastrow).Copy startRange.Offset(1, 2)
Range("A5:A" & lastrow).Copy startRange.Offset(1, 1)

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this apply to copying data from one sheet to another in any case? I mean finding the range once and using it to copy all the columns?

Comment: @user3504466 yeah, basically `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp)` is going to find the bottom row of data.  So if you want all your data on the same row you should only call that once.  Because after you copy the data the "bottom" row is going to be lower, etc.